# Run javascript function when the page loads

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a JS example downloaded and I wish to ask you if is any chance to start on window load.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    $.fn.rotate.serialize();

    var gear1 = document.getElementById('gear1');
    var gear2 = document.getElementById('gear2');
    $('#centerpiece').on('mouseenter',function() {
        if(!gear1.isRotating && !gear2.isRotating) {
            gear1.isRotating = true;
            gear2.isRotating = true;
            $(gear1).rotate(360,{speed:140},function() {
                gear1.isRotating = true;
                $(this).rotate('reset');
            });
            $(gear2).rotate(360,{speed:110},function() {
                gear2.isRotating = true;
                $(this).rotate('reset');
            });
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: *if is any chance to start on window load.* What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed window.onload and now it runs without mouseover.

```
if(!gear1.isRotating && !gear2.isRotating) {
        gear1.isRotating = true;
        gear2.isRotating = true;
        $('#gear1').rotate(360,{speed:140},function() {
            gear1.isRotating = true;
            $('#gear1').rotate('reset');
        });
        $('#gear2').rotate(360,{speed:110},function() {
            gear2.isRotating = true;
            $('#gear2').rotate('reset');
        });
    }
```

Comment: $('#centerpiece').on('mouseenter',function() { this is the function that it make it functional on mouse over

Comment: So you want to remove the mouseover?

Comment: yes. I want to start the script when I access the page

Comment: this function is ok, it is starting on paging load but it is rotate the whole elements

Comment: Can you provide a js fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8x62woza/ or you can try the whole example on http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Creating-Element-Rotation-Animations.html

Comment: Edited my post again. Try that.